# JS conditions with "!" (Exclamation Mark) not working

Tags: javascript

Hi I wanted to run a condition `if` user input is "`!`" (Exclamation Mark) then do something. But not working.

```
if (userInput == "!") {
  console.log("Done");
} else console.log("Nope");
```

But not working but regular character like a b c works.

Comment: what is `userInput` ? a variable ? how can we reproduce this error ?

Comment: Do you think the problem is in the code you've shown?

Comment: userInput comes from input field

Comment: @traktor it doesn't work

Comment: So the problem _is_ in the code in the question? Easy then, you haven’t defined `userInput`. Worth opening another question for the troubling fact that “regular character like a b c works”, as they shouldn’t with that code

Comment: Please provide more information about the `userInput`, like what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You are not described about userInput, so lets assume

```
let userInput = 'i'

if(userInput && userInput.length && userInput.includes('!')) {
   // true
   console.log('done')
}
else {
   // false
   console.log('Nope')
}
```

you need this condition `userInput && userInput.length && userInput.includes('!')`